# Shopify Different Collection Banners for Desktop / Mobile

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

Basically what I'm trying to achieve here is to have different collection banner image for desktop & mobile .

Did a lot of research but couldn't find any solution ,

Any help is totally appreciated here ,

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

1. Create a theme section and add it to the collection template
2. In section settings add 2 `image_picker` inputs ([reference](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/settings#basic-input-setting-types))
3. Add your HTML/Liquid code to render those images
4. Use CSS media query to show/hide images based on screen size ([reference](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp))
5. Go to your section in theme customizations and upload your images
6. Done!

Comment: I dont think I'm  able to do that , can you please share more details here @Karim